# How is squeezeback implemented in browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm interested in adding [squeezeback](http://www.althos.com/tutorial/TV-advertising-tutorial-squeeze-back-squeezeback.html) to the videos in my webpages.

Is there an easy way to do this without implementing it inside the video itself?

Answer (score 1):

Put the video inside a div with an id.
Use jquery to change the size of the video element (probably with %s).
Add an element to the div after the video element (.appendElement())
Fill it with another thing.

Answer (score 1):

`<video>` is an HTML element just like any other, so you could use CSS and javascript to resize it, place other elements around and over it, and so on.

I'd probably put the video inside a relatively positioned div. At the appropriate moment, use a bit of script to scale the video accordingly, then introduce more elements absolutely positioned above/below/beside it. The world is your oyster, give it a go then report back!

Thinking about it, Mozilla's [Popcorn.js](http://popcornjs.org/) might be helpful with this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

That would be overlapping absolute divs:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="background">contents here</div>
    <div id="videoWrapper">
        <video></video>
    </div>
</div>

#container{
    position:relative;
}

#container > *{
    position:absolute; /*to allow stacking*/
    top: 0;            /*stretch to container*/
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0
}
```

Then, to scale the video, take a look at [this post](http://scratchpaper.tk/blog/preserve-an-html-elements-aspect-ratio/) regarding "scaling" an element and preserve the aspect ratio.